# How to find doucments with negetive search in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Here is some sample documents in Mongo collection. While I am dealing with negative numbers its not giving me the correct results as expected. I wanted to search between -2 and -99. so here the max value is -2 and least value is -99. but my search gives me zero records for the same.

```
> db.btch_insrt.find({z: {"$gt" : -99, "$lt" : -2}}).count()
288
> db.btch_insrt.find({z: {"$gt" : -2, "$lt" : -99}}).count()
0


{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d29f"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 14, "z" : -4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a0"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 15, "z" : -5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a1"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 16, "z" : -6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a2"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 17, "z" : -7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a3"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 18, "z" : -8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a4"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 19, "z" : -9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a5"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 20, "z" : -10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a6"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 21, "z" : -11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a7"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 22, "z" : -12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a8"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 23, "z" : -13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2a9"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 24, "z" : -14 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2aa"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 25, "z" : -15 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2ab"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 26, "z" : -16 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2ac"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 27, "z" : -17 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2ad"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 28, "z" : -18 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2ae"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 29, "z" : -19 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2af"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 30, "z" : -20 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2b0"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 31, "z" : -21 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2b1"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 32, "z" : -22 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59383e867421a8c9d281d2b2"), "foo" : "bar", "baz" : 33, "z" : -23 }
```

Comment: Your first query with results appears to match your intent (z > -99 and z < -2), however the logic of your second query is incorrect and will always have zero results (z > -2 and z<-99). Is the first query not doing what you expected? Can you provide more information on the difference between your expected outcome and the actual outcome?

Comment: Like Stennie mentioned, 2nd query was wrong.

For query between `{ "z": { $gte: NumberInt(-99), $lte: NumberInt(-2) } }`

Comment: Do you need to find those in -99..-2 range. Or all __except__ those in that range?

Comment: Thank you for your quick glance Stennie !! I accept my logic was wrong while dealing with the query. Second one is accurate one.

Answer (score 0):

Query for between use `$gte`(inclusive) else `$gt`(exclusive)

`{ "z": { $gt: NumberInt(-99), $lt: NumberInt(-2) } }`

Negative search

`{ "z": { $not: { $gt: NumberInt(-99), $lt: NumberInt(-2) } } }`

Or

`{ $or: [ { "z": { $gt: NumberInt(-2) } }, { "z": { $lt: NumberInt(-99) } } ] }`

Comment: MongoDB Enterprise > db.btch_insrt.find({z: {$elemMatch: {"$gt" : -2, "$lt" : -99}}}).count()
0

Comment: Sorry, I realised I did not add $not before